# AngularJS user-friendly profiles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm in trouble with AngularJS route. I have a following code: http://pastebin.com/Q2FqRVrc and I have no idea how to add short profiles like: http://domain.tld/username

Any tips how to do it?

Comment: Please move your code into your question. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding your code, maybe we could help you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the link you have found is for using the built-in ng-route directive, but you have tagged this question with angular-ui-router. This is what the config would look like using ui-router's [`$stateProvider`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) to configure your app.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    // Configure my routes with ui-router
    $stateProvider
      .state('user-profile', {
        url: '/:username',
        templateUrl: 'app/profiles/template.html',
        controller: 'UserProfileCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'upCtrl'
      })
      // These are nested states, under `user-profile`
      .state('user-profile.images', {
        template: '<div my-images-directive></div>'
      })
      .state('user-profile.friends', {
        template: '<div my-friends-directive></div>'
      })
      .state('otherPage', {
        url: '/other-page',
        templateUrl: 'app/otherpage/template.html'
      });
  });
```

To go to a state, you would use the [$state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) object's `$state.go` method.

```
$state.go('user-profile', {username: $scope.user.name});
```

To get rid of hashes `#`, you will need need to turn on HTML5 mode with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`

Comment: @delco - Did this help you? Please provide some feedback

Comment: doesn't work :( Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: Which module failed to load? Did you inject ui router `angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])` ? Do you have the files for ui-router included on your page?